# Why is my global list not getting appended in Python when using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

When I run my code the global list stays empty, even though it should get the entries.
The test doesn't get appended, is it likely due to multi processing?

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import time

uncounted = []
test = [{'id': 'UC8YCf2zyqY8E7-CCOnr_kQA', 'name': 'dominic alting:('}, {'id': 'UCxm1n3Hil3l9mmPWcONd4Dg', 'name': 'Toes Jr.'}]

dir_path = "./json/"
i = 0
xi = -1


def load(pathD):
    pathD = test
    global uncounted
    return pathD


def multiprocessing_func(dp):
    global uncounted
    time.sleep(2)
    u = load(dp)
    uncounted.append(u)


errors = []


def main(xi):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        starttime = time.time()
        processes = []
        for i in range(0, 10):
            print(f'{i} has started')
            i += 1
            xi += 1
            try:
                p = multiprocessing.Process(
                    target=multiprocessing_func, args=(os.listdir(dir_path)[xi],))
                processes.append(p)
                p.start()
            except:
                errors.append(i)
                print(f"{i} - no more path")

        for process in processes:
            process.join()
        print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
        print(uncounted)

main(xi)
```

Tried appending without global but then I get the same outcome

Comment: When you create another process, that process gets its own copy of `uncounted`. If you want to share lists between processes, there are several methods of which the `multiprocessing` module's [Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) class will probably be the most convenient for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function, that changes the list, isn't running, because there is no file. This must be always reviewed.